# optimal transcoding format (3d viewport and VSE)?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

1080p workspace. Not sure if I use the correct words or not to describe things, bear with me.

Due to pc limitations I need to render out a project in the VSE premature so its easier to deal with. The original footage is 8 bit h.264. Additionally I need to render out a particle effect I made in the 3d Viewport before adding it to the VSE project

I need to be able to re-render the output a couple of times (1-3) and not get artifacts.

I had been using 16 bit PNG for both the vse and 3d viewport. And this fulfills the requirements I think.

I'm wondering if there is a higher format I should consider, or a lower format that fulfills the duty but is more savvy on space. Ultimately the project will be rendered out h.264 and get artifacts, just I need a format for the editing stage that won't increase these artifacts anymore than they have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEXR for a multitude of reasons. Half EXR is superior in every way compared to every other format if you are [intra | inter] pipeline at equivalent bit depth.

Comment: some words too big there. So I would choose OpenEXR; then RGB; Float (Half); wut codec should I use with it (I have to convert to h.264 at the end)? and Would I use RGBA just when rendering in the 3d viewport since I'd have alpha channel there? or should I always use RGBA if I have to render it to h.264 at the end? "if you are [intra | inter] pipeline at equivalent bit depth." doesn't make sense to me, explain? and does openexr multilayer differ in what way?

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: If you are doing work, always use OpenEXR. Once you are done, encode to the H264, or better, encode to still images (TIFF, JPEG, etc.) high quality, then use an external encoder to encode from the still images.

Comment: okay, i'll just use whatever codec with RGB Float (half) OpenEXR and see if that improves things enough